# Regular expression in classpath Silk Central

Tags: regex, silk-central

I'm working with Silk Central and I need to add all the **.jar** files I need in the classpath. For the application I have four projects: `app_EAR`,`app_EJB`, `app_WEB`,`app_TEST` inside the `app` directory.

The .jar files I need to add are located in the lib folder inside its corresponding project:
`C:\app\app_EAR\lib` and `C:\app\app_TEST\lib`

To add the files to the classpath I have done it in the following way individually:
`app_EAR \lib\*; app_TEST\lib\*`

But my question comes now, is it possible to indicate that it includes all the **.jar** files it finds in any lib folder within the app directory with any depth?

I have tried it this way:
`app*\lib*` to look in any directory that contains the word app (to take `app_EAR` and `app_TEST`) and inside each one of them the folder **lib** that contains the **.jar**. Silk Central is not able to recognize this regular expression.

I have also tried it like this: `**/lib/**.jar` to find all the **lib** folders regardless of their depth in the directory, but it also does not recognize it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not work. Java does not support searching the classpath recursively. Silk Central just passes this information to the Java VM.